# Brunch set LOGGY_STACKS=true

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, error-handling, brunch

I am developing an app with brunch. I am new to it and to trace an error I have to enable LOGGY_STACKS=true. How can I set it up?

```
Stack trace was suppressed. Run with `LOGGY_STACKS=true` to see the trace.
```

Comment: *sigh* It just keeps on changing... just stumbled upon it now too and I have no idea where to set this either. Would be nice if they specified it in their output.

Comment: Its referring to an environment variable on *NIX systems just `export LOGGY_STACKS=true; brunch watch --server -p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not keen on "permanently" modifying your system environment vars and affecting other Brunch based projects, you can use the `set` command within your NPM `scripts` definition in `package.json`, followed by a `&&` combinator and the `brunch` command.

This technique should work on both Unix and Windows machines.

```
// example package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set LOGGY_STACKS=true && brunch watch --server",
    "serve": "npm run start",
    "build": "brunch b -p --env production",
    "clean": "rm -rf public dist"
  }
}
```

For reference, I use `start` and `stop` to cover my bases as not all NPM based services use the same initialization task names.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Windows, there's a few ways to go about setting this in your System Environment variables. The way to find it via your System / Computer properties is:

- On your desktop, right-click "**Computer**", then click "**Properties**".
- Click "**Advanced system settings**" (see image).

[image]

- In the **System Properties** dialog, click the **Advanced** tab and click the **Environment Variables...** button.
- Once there, under the first section where it says "*User variables for YOUR_USER_NAME*", click **New** and add **`LOGGY_STACKS`** as the name and **`true`** as the value.

[image]

- **OK** your way out of those windows / panels, close any command-line windows you had open to run brunch, re-open and try it out now.

It should give you lengthier stack-traces; hopefully it'll help you narrow down your issue in your configuration.